# select row based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro to move data from one sheet to another based on matching cell values.

Let's say I have 2 sheets, Sheet1 & Sheet2, respectively.

Sheet1 contains data that I wanted to be copied into Sheet2.

Sheet2 contains a value in column "C", and this value with have multiple matches in column "C" of 
Sheet1 (which are already sorted and same values are grouped together).

My overall goal is to copy cells from Sheet1 to Sheet2 based on matching values in column "C". I want to insert these values one row below the row with matching column "C" values.

The difficulty lies in the fact that the range of values copied from Sheet1 to Sheet2 will differ with each different value in Column "c" of Sheet2, because there will be a different number of rows with respect to a particular cell value.

(I would show a simple picture for this, but it won't allow me to post a picture due to low post count - I can email this if needed for clarification)

I am okay with basic macro stuff and rely on the Macro Record for some stuff as well. But with my current knowledge and lack of the macro recorder's ability to make a macro like this, I am just stumped!

My request:

1. Help with macro that selects a range of cells based on matching cell values to copy
2. Help with inserting the copied range starting 1 row below the cell value of interest (cell value is row 2, insert cells starting at row 3)
3. Have this repeated for each value listed in Sheet2

I think I can figure the basic coding with this. If I can just get help with the particular string that does what I am looking for would be great!  I am not trying to just be handed the answer, but I have been working on this issue for 8+hrs and can't find anything online that is similar to this...

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing this, but I would like to help you. Can you post the worksheet layout please? In text format? Also, you can upload an image using http://imgur.com and link it in your post. That would be helpful.

Comment: User1274820 - Thank you for your response and offer to help!
The image can be located at http://i.imgur.com/UCwtXYq.jpg

How can I post the workbook? I don't see anyway to do so :(

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes that you have sorted the data as you have in the example:

```
Sub transfer()
'If everything is sorted, you can do it like this:
Dim x, y 'x is the sheet1 row, y is the sheet2 row
y = 2    'they start at the same place x = 2, y = 2
For x = 2 To Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1) = Sheets(2).Cells(y, 1) Then 'If the cell value matches
        Sheets(1).Range("A" & x).Copy                     'Copy the cell value from Sheet1
        Sheets(2).Cells(y + 1, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown    'And insert it below the Sheet2 Cell
        'Then copy the rest of the data (columns C and D)
        Sheets(1).Range("C" & x & ":D" & x).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(y + 1, 2)
    Else
        x = x - 1 'We haven't found a match for this cell yet so check it again
    End If
    y = y + 1     'After incrementing y
Next x
End Sub
```

Sorry for slow reply - I can explain the code to you soon if need be!
Hope this helps! :)

[image]

I wrote this specifically for the example you gave me, so hopefully you are able to build upon this concept if your needs change.

Comment: Thank you @user1274820! I can't thank you enough for your help! I am playing around with the macro to get it to suit my needs. Thanks again - you just saved me hours of copying/pasting!

Comment: Np! Glad to help! best of luck :)